# /usr/share/vim/vimrc taking precedence over ~/.vimrc for textwidth

Tags: vimrc

Here is my `${HOME}/.vimrc` :

```
set textwidth=0
set history=100
```

(FWIW, inverting their order has no effect, as one would expect.)

It is read by `vim` (`:echo $MYVIMRC` returns the correct path), and indeed `set history` (actually included to check if it was a `.vimrc` inclusion issue) is taken into account, but not `set textwidth` :

```
:verbose set textwidth
  textwidth=78
    Last set from /usr/share/vim/vimrc

:verbose set history
  history=100
    Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

Yet if I source my `.vimrc` it *does* set `textwidth` :

```
:so ~/.vimrc
:verbose set textwidth
  textwidth=0
    Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

What's wrong, and what can I do to force `textwidth` to be set by my user `.vimrc` ?

Comment: What's the output of `:scriptnames`?

Comment: @Ralf Nevermind, see answer.

Answer (score 1):

From `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` :

```
" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")

  […]

  " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78
```

Apparently these settings override basic custom `.vimrc` settings.  I replaced `set textwidth=0` in my `.vimrc` with

```
  autocmd VimEnter * set textwidth=0
```

and now `vim` behaves as I expected.

Comment: This looks as if someone copied (parts of) `vimrc_example.vim` to `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`. I think this example is not intended as system vimrc, but as a example to start your personal vimrc. Anyway I don't understand where your initial problem comes from, as `textwidth=78` is only set for text files.

Comment: Indeed, `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` starts as `" An example for a vimrc file"…  This is the default `vim-7.4` Slackware installation.  As for my initial problem, well, I was editing a text file.  ;)

Comment: Your solution will only work for the first text file you open (on the command-line), the second one you open will have a textwidth of 78 again. Complain to your Linux distribution, open a bug report asking them to fix that, they shouldn't be shipping vimrc_example as the system-wide vimrc.